# How to save state of custom attributes in backing component of a composite component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I've created a simple composite component with a backing component class. I'd like to save the state of a certain attributes of this class. Therefore I use the `StateHelper` within setter/getter of the attribute. From my perspective, if the component is derived from `UINamingContainer` this is all that needs to be done to let JSF save and restore state.

Unfortunately this does not work as expected. There is a debug statement, that should print the state of the component to console whenever accessed. I expect to have state restored when the page is reentered (through navigation), but the state is always resolved to null.

Example code:

```
@FacesComponent("myComponent")
public class MyComponent extends UINamingContainer {

enum PropertyKeys {selected}

public void selectionListener(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
             ...
    // do some stuff here

}

public void setSelected(final Collection<Integer> selected) {

    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.selected, selected);

}

public Collection<Integer> getSelected() {
    Collection<Integer> state = (Collection<Integer>) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.selected);

    System.out.println("State: "+state);

    return state;
}
```

What else needs to be done to keep state of a composite component saved during requests? In this case I'd like to provide a composite component that encapsulates multiple tables with row-selection features. I want the selected rows to be saved during requests within the component, not bound to a managed bean.

In this special case, there will be a lot of selectable tables in the composite component and I want the composite component itself to keep track of selections so composite component users don't need to deal with multiple selection attributes.

---

**Update:** I created a simple example:

Backing class:

```
@FacesComponent("StateSavinComponent")
public class StateSavingComponent extends UINamingContainer{

    private String someText;

    private Object[] state;

    @Override
    public Object saveState(final FacesContext context) {
        if (state == null) {
            state = new Object[2];
        }

        state[0] = super.saveState(context);
        state[1] = someText;
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(final FacesContext context, final Object state) {
        this.state = (Object[]) state;
        super.restoreState(context, this.state[0]);
        someText =  (String) this.state[1];
    }

    public void setSomeText(final String someText) {
        this.someText = someText;
    }

    public String getSomeText() {
        return someText;
    }

}
```

Composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface componentType="StateSavinComponent">

    </cc:interface>   

    <cc:implementation>

        <h:inputText value="#{cc.someText}" />

    </cc:implementation>

</html>
```

First page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:example="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/example">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">

        <example:stateSaving/>      

        <h:commandButton action="page2.xhtml" value="next" />

    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Second page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">

            <h:commandButton action="example.xhtml" value="back" />

    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

1. Input value in text field
2. navigate to page2.xhtml
3. navigate back to example.xhtml
4. The input field is empty, but should contain the value entered previously
5. Setting breakpoints in the backing class
6. saveState and restoreState seem to me to be called in the wrong order

Comment: "Custom component" != "Composite component". Please pay attention to this terminology in your future questions. I deleted my answer because it was targeted on a custom component. I'm not sure about composites, but I know that there are some bugs around state saving in composites in Mojarra. See also among others http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2040 I'm however not sure if this is related. I've never had the need to create/design such a composite, so I can't tell from experience. I can only suggest to take a look to `<t:saveState>` component (which is a fullworthy custom component!)

Comment: Thx for that information. I was not aware that there is a difference in state saving between custom and composite components. I'll take a look at the Tomahawk component. And thank you very much for the ultra-fast reply :-)